# How to iterate over all byte values (overflowing_literals in `0..256`)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to iterate over all possible byte (`u8`) values. Unfortunately my range literals in `0..256` are cast to `u8` and `256` overflows:

```
fn foo(byte: u8) {
    println!("{}", byte);
}

fn main() {
    for byte in 0..256 {
        foo(byte);
        println!("Never executed.");
    }
    for byte in 0..1 {
        foo(byte);
        println!("Executed once.");
    }
}
```

The above compiles with:

```
warning: literal out of range for u8
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     for byte in 0..256 {
  |                    ^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

The first loop body is never executed at all.

My workaround is very ugly and feels brittle because of the cast:

```
for short in 0..256 {
    let _explicit_type: u16 = short;
    foo(short as u8);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: For starters, you can lose `explicitType` and write `for i in 0..256`, as long as you cast in `foo(i as u8)`. Then `i` will be of type `i32`. That's only marginally better though.

Comment: @delnan: Your tip has brought me to `(0..256).map(|byte| byte as u8)`, which is just as unintuitive, but at least points out the magic to the reader. And it's still not good :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is issue [Unable to create a range with max value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23635).

The gist of it is that `byte` is inferred to be `u8`, and therefore `0..256` is represented as a `Range<u8>` but unfortunately `256` overflows as an `u8`.

The current work-around is to use a larger integral type and cast to `u8` later on since `256` is actually never reached.

There is a [RFC for inclusive range with `...`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1192) which has entered final comment period; maybe in the future it'll be possible to have `for byte in 0...255` or its alternative `(0..255).inclusive()`.

Comment: Right now there is open [pull-request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30884) implementing this feature.

Answer (score 9):

As of Rust 1.26, inclusive ranges are stabilized using the syntax `..=`, so you can write this as:

```
for byte in 0..=255 {
    foo(byte);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Kind of strange that such a common case needed a relatively new notation.

Comment: Syntax ends up inspiring the longest debates, it took a while to settle on `..=` rather than `...` or something else.