# What is the ..= (dot dot equals) operator in Rust?

Tags: syntax, rust, operators

I saw this `..=` operator in some Rust code:

```
for s in 2..=9 {
    // some code here
}
```

What is it?

Answer (score 45):

This is the [**inclusive range operator**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html).

The range `x..=y` contains all values `>= x` and `<= y`, i.e. “from `x` up to and *including* `y`”.

This is in contrast to the *non-inclusive* range operator `x..y`, which doesn't include `y` itself.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", (10..20) .collect::<Vec<_>>());
    println!("{:?}", (10..=20).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}

// Output:
//
//     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
//     [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

### Match expressions

You can also use `start..=end` as a pattern in a `match` expression to match any value in the (inclusive) range.

```rust
match fahrenheit_temperature {
    70..=89  => println!("What lovely weather!"),
    _        => println!("Ugh, I'm staying in."),
}
```

(Using an *exclusive* range `start..end` as a pattern is an [experimental feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37854).)

### History

Inclusive ranges used to be an experimental nightly-only feature, and were written `...` before.

As of Rust 1.26, it's officially part of the language, and written `..=`.

(Before inclusive ranges existed, you actually couldn't create, say, a range of byte values including `255u8`. Because that'd be `0..256`, and `256` is out of the `u8` range! This is [issue #23635](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23635).)

### See also

- The [Rust 1.26 release blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html#inclusive-ranges-with-)'s introduction to `..=`.
- [StackOverflow: How do I include the end value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698191/how-do-i-include-the-end-value-in-a-range)

Comment: You might want to add some detail about why this new syntax was necessary, for example the difference between `0u8..(n+1)` and `0u8..=n` when `n == 255`.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that `a..=b` can be used in a match expression pattern, but `a..b` in that location is experimental (`exclusive_range_pattern`)!

Comment: Regarding @mcarton's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296410/